# Microstrategy selector metric

Tags: selector, dashboard, microstrategy, metric

I have made a metric selector to visualize on a board, using an attribute with the name of the metrics and a metric with a 'case', the selector works fine, but the values are unformatted, some idea of how to format them? The number format does not work anywhere on the board.

I hope you can give me a hand, thanks

edit:

code of metric

Case(([Metric Selector]="Real Vol");vol_real01;([Metric Selector]="Real Spd");(spd_real02*100);([Metric Selector]="Real Res");res_real01;([Metric Selector]="Ppto Vol");vol_ppto01;([Metric Selector]="Ppto Spd");(spd_ppto02*100);([Metric Selector]="Ppto Res");res_ppto01;([Metric Selector]="R Vol Ant");vol_realant01;([Metric Selector]="R Spd Ant");(spd_realant02*100);([Metric Selector]="R Res Ant");res_realant01;([Metric Selector]="P Vol Ant");vol_pptoant01;([Metric Selector]="P Spd Ant");(spd_pptoant01*100);([Metric Selector]="P Res Ant");res_pptoant01;"")

Comment: Please post your code so that we can help you :)

Comment: 1: I have created an attribute with the name of the metrics.
2: a metric from the attribute (Max (attribute))
3: in the report dataset I have created a metric with the case:

Comment: Plecase edit your question and include your code to make it easier to be found by other users.

Comment: here was the code, edit the post to be read better as you have asked me.

Excuse my English, I'm not a native. Thank you

Comment: Are you using a document or a dashboard?